# While creating configure product it's associate product are virtual instead of simple

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

My magento version magento 2.0.0 when i am trying to create configure product with it's associate simple product it gives one configure product and it's associate product but it's type virtual instead of simple.

I miss any configure stuff? or having some bug with this version?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not set the weight before generation of children's products. Depending on this field the Magento decides what type of product is created

Comment: For those who wander: you must put weight on *configurable* when you create configuration through wizard, not on the different configuration. You simply can't actually, on 2.2.2. It's specified nowhere, that's the pb.

Comment: I've been tripped up by this numerous times. Thanks for clarifying.
However, for one of my clients, who sells paints, this process is counter intuitive. If you sell a brand of white paint in different volumes (1 liter, 5 liters, 10 liters) then the weight will be different - so setting weight for the parent seems odd.

Comment: when you are done with all wizard steps and selected all product then you will get input to edit weight for each product before save main product.

Answer (score 3):

In Magento 2.0 products become virtual if you have not configured weight for it. Most likely you have generated configurable product via wizard and missed weight.